# Pull from a Branch, and push to another

Tags: git, github, branch, gitlab, git-branch

I have a 'master' branch, and a 'bugfix' branch.
this bugfix branch needs to be always updated with master commits,
but i need to push to its own branch.

i tried

```
git branch -f --track bugfix origin/master
```

and tried set-upstream too
but seems to set both, pull and push from/to 'master'.

Answer (score 1):

If you pull the remote master branch into master by doing a git pull you can push it to the remote bugfix branch like this:

```
git push origin master:bugfix
```

That is assuming the name of your remote is origin.

I hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
mkdir -p git
cd git
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
cd repo
git branch bugfix
git checkout bugfix
git push origin bugfix
git checkout master

git branch --set-upstream-to=bugfix
echo 'hallo' > hallo.txt
git add hallo.txt
git commit -m 'lolz'
git config push.default upstream
git push
```

So it will push master to origin/bugfix and pull origin/bugfix to bugfix.